# Explain why output 10 will come in c program

Tags: c

explain about why output 10 will come?

```
main()
{

   for(printf("1");!printf("0");printf("2"))
    {
    printf("hello");
    }   
}
```

output:

```
10
```

Comment: Read about how for(;;) works. The very [first link](http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-for-loop-statement.aspx) that comes up in google is reasonable.

Comment: Think of what parts a for loop is composed of and what `!printf()` evaluates to.

Comment: I did answer to the question, but I cannot understand why you are asking it. If you are unable to find out (and that means looking for, and searching) the answer, you should not program and do something else of your life. Your teacher probably wanted to exercise your skills (so asking for help is counterproductive to you).

Answer (score 5):

According to its [printf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) man page, the `printf` function returns

> the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings)

so, the initialization part of the `for` is run once: `printf("1")`; it puts the `1` character into the buffer of `stdout`. Then the condition is evaluated `!printf("0");` since `printf("0")` is evaluated, it puts the `0` character into the buffer of `stdout` and returns the number of output characters i.e. `1` so the condition is false, and the `for` loop exists.

At last, `main` is exiting the program, at that time only the `stdout` buffers are flushed.

To be pedantic, your program would have a different behavior when, for unlikely reasons, the `stdout` cannot be written successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Because at printf("1") it executes the statement as it is.
then printf("0") prints 0 on the screen and  returns a value 1. when you negate it it gives a value equal to false in C. so the for loop meet its ending condition and exits.